# sorting pandas dataframe based on row frequency

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df:

```
Name Score
AAAA    4
AAAA    7
AAAA   12
AAAA   13
BBBB    1
BBBB    1
CCCC    1
CCCC    2
CCCC   27
```

I want a new dataframe that has values from the df only if each "Name" occurs atleast 3 time. i.e. the desired output is

```
Name Score
AAAA    4
AAAA    7
AAAA   12
AAAA   13
CCCC    1
CCCC    2
CCCC   27
```

I know df.groupby['Name'] gives the frequency of each name.
 Any suggestions how I can use this info in getting the desired output. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

use `groupby` and `filter`:

```
df.groupby("Name").filter(lambda df:df.shape[0] > 2)
```

Comment: I kindof disagree with using df as the variable name here, I also think I'd just use len: `df.groupby("Name").filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2)`

Comment: `len` takes as long as it takes to iterate so shape is the way to go. Maybe add `.index` in the end to return the names only.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a more elegant way, but this will work.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['AAAA' ,'AAAA' ,'AAAA' ,'AAAA' ,'BBBB' ,'BBBB' ,'CCCC' ,'CCCC' ,'CCCC'],
    'Score': [4 ,7 ,12 ,13 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,2 ,27]})

Counts = pd.DataFrame(df['Name'].value_counts())
df[df['Name'].isin(list(Counts[Counts[0] >= 3].index))]
```